# R remove all but the first occurence

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  id     date  time
1  1 15-12-15 10:30
2  2 15-12-15 08:30
3  3 16-12-15 10:30
4  1 16-12-15 08:30
```

Which can be created like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,1),
                 date=c("15-12-15", "15-12-15", "16-12-15", "16-12-15"),
                 time=c("10:30", "08:30", "10:30", "08:30"))
```

I want to remove all rows that have a duplicate `id`. If duplicates are found, then I want to retain the `id` that occurred first (by date and time), and remove all others

The way I'm currently doing it is sorting by `date`, and then:

```
df <- subset(df, duplicated(df$id) == FALSE)
```

So that will retain all rows where `id` isn't duplicated, but the retention criteria isn't clear. It seems to just keep the first occurence that it encounters when sorted by date?

Is there a way to do this without having to date sort first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(paste(date, time), format = "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")) %>%
   arrange(datetime) %>%
   slice(1) %>%
   select(-datetime)


#     id     date   time           
#  <dbl>   <fctr> <fctr>           
#1     1 15-12-15  10:30 
#2     2 15-12-15  08:30 
#3     3 16-12-15  10:30
```

We create a `POSIXct` object pasting the `date` and `time` column together, `arrange` them accordingly and select the first observation (one which occur earliest) from each group.

Answer (score 1):

We need the `fromLast = TRUE`

```
df[!duplicated(df$id, fromLast = TRUE),]
#    id     date  time
#2  2 15-12-15 08:30
#3  3 16-12-15 10:30
#4  1 16-12-15 08:30
```

---

If we need to consider the 'date' and 'time' (which is already ordered in the example)

```
library(lubridate)
df[!duplicated(df$id[with(df, order(id, ymd_hm(paste(date, time))))], fromLast = TRUE),]
#    id     date  time
#2  2 15-12-15 08:30
#3  3 16-12-15 10:30
#4  1 16-12-15 08:30
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` includes an enhanced `unique()` function which accepts a `by` parameter to specify the columns to be used for the uniqueness check:

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df, key = c("date", "time")), by = "id")
```

> ```
>    id     date  time
> 1:  2 15-12-15 08:30
> 2:  1 15-12-15 10:30
> 3:  3 16-12-15 10:30
> ```

`setDT()` coerces `df` to `data.table` class. The `key` parameter sorts `df` and marks it as sorted.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative using `dplyr` can be:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date, time) %>%
  top_n(1)
```

which gives:

```
     id     date   time
  <dbl>   <fctr> <fctr>
1     2 15-12-15  08:30
2     1 15-12-15  10:30
3     3 16-12-15  10:30
```